# Why should i mock objects?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, android-testing

I want to some feedback on why I should use mockito when testing my android application and also does anyone have any real examples of mockito would be extremely useful.

Such as a git project with various use cases of mocking android tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking objects is commonly used it unit testing.

Unit tests are made to assure that the flow of instructions in your code is correct, and the logic is OK, but doing it separately from other classes/objects. Just one class at a time.

So, when your code makes use of any object of other class - you mock it and it behaves like correct object of mocked class, without actually making object of that class.

I suggest you reading about unit testing, injection, mockito.

Hope it helps you to get the idea behing mock.

Answer (score 3):

Mock objects are useful when you want to test part of an application when either the rest of the application isn't written yet, or when you don't want to actually have the side effects that the real code causes (such as writing to a database).

Comment: One more good reason to use mocks (besides the ones already stated), is to avoid making tests run slowly because of interactions with external systems (for example a web service). Using mocks completely removes the slowdown introduced by the communication with those systems